# How to set two custom actionbar button in left and right in android?

Tags: android

I am Using Sherlock library and i also implement with myself. My problem is that i added two items in menu, now i want 1 item in left of actionbar and second in right of actionbar. How to to it?

Comment: Do you mean: `[A][ActionBar][B]`? Or `[A ActionBar B]`?

Comment: yes i want [A] [ActionBar] [B]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can create such action bar, but it's little more complicated than inflating a menu. Menu created in `onCreateOptionsMenu()` method will be always aligned to right, placed in split action bar or hidden under the menu key.

If you want your action bar to contain just two menu items - one on the left edge and the other on the right edge - you have to create custom view in the action bar.

The custom view layout will be something like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ImageButton android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_item1"
                 android:background="?attr/actionBarItemBackground"
                 android:layout_width="?attr/actionBarSize"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                 android:scaleType="centerInside"
                 android:id="@+id/item1"
                 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                 android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

    <ImageButton android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_item2"
                 android:background="?attr/actionBarItemBackground"
                 android:layout_width="?attr/actionBarSize"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                 android:scaleType="centerInside"
                 android:id="@+id/item2"
                 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                 android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Define in the theme that you want to use custom view. The theme should contain:

```xml
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">
    <item name="displayOptions">showCustom</item>
    <item name="android:displayOptions">showCustom</item>
</style>
```

Set the custom view in the activity (or fragment):

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ActionBar ab = getSherlock().getActionBar();
    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View customView = li.inflate(R.layout.my_custom_view, null);
    ab.setCustomView(customView);

    ImageButton ibItem1 = (ImageButton) customView.findViewById(R.id.item1);
    ibItem1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // ...
        }
    });

    ImageButton ibItem2 = (ImageButton) customView.findViewById(R.id.item2);
    ibItem2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // ...
        }
    });
}
```

You have to add the click listeners for the menu items. You cannot use `onOptionsItemSelected()` in this case.

Answer (score 7):

Additionally to [Tomik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14211619/1993204). You need to add

```
ab.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
```

in onCreate method, otherwise custom view does not appear (at least for me).

Comment: i used actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true); and actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM); both. But still layout showing in right most side...any suggestion!