# How to place Button rightside of logo in ActionbarSherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

Unlike previous questions to customize actionbar as [**[A][B] ACTION_BAR**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14210454/how-to-set-two-custom-actionbar-button-in-left-and-right-in-android) or [**[A] ACTION_BAR [B]**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14210454/how-to-set-two-custom-actionbar-button-in-left-and-right-in-android),

I'd like to make **[LOGO][A] ACTION_BAR [B][C]** style. One button "A" is placed right-side of the logo (but left aligned) where normally title text is placed.
(*Note that A,B,C are buttons*)

Is there another way except to use [setCustomView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setCustomView%28int%29)? small changes but replacing whole actionbar view makes lot of works.

Maybe a kind of overlaid button view and logo width value can help or replace title textview to ButtonView also can make it, but I hardly imagine how to acheive.

Comment: the best way to achieve this is really using setCustomView(), it's easy to achieve it with just one layout. The second option which I can think is to create the logo + button and place it as your logo and override home button onClick. But that means when user click the button your icon will be highlighted too.

Comment: @Android-Developer // Thanks for the feedback. I'll try and will post my code later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right side of the button:

```
 //Inflate the custom view
    View customNav = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_view, null);

    //Bind to its state change
    ((Button)customNav.findViewById(R.id.button)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // DO your stuff

        }
    }); 

    //Attach to the action bar
    getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(customNav);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
```