# how to get the action bar button? findviewbyid seems doesn't work

Tags: android

Suppose I have two buttons, one is an action button which is in the action bar(@+id/button1). And another is common button in the layout(@+id/button2).

How can I set the button1 disabled when i click the button2?

findViewById(button1) seems not work. it will return null.

this is my menu xml:

`<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:title="submit"
        android:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>`

and this is my mainacticity:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.my, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.button1 ) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);/*which return null*/
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            button1.setEnabled(false);/*what i failed to do*/
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Share the code you have tried yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.Create a variable MenuItem in your Activity class

```
    MenuItem menuItem;
```

2. Find your variable in onCreateOptionsMenu

```
    @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.item_circuit);
            return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        }
```

3. Disable the item in your buttonClick method

   ```
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onClick(View v) {
                       menuItem.setEnabled(false);
                   }
               });
   ```

Comment: Maybe I got the story wrong. I want to disabled button1(action button) when i click button2(common button)

Answer (score 1):

Try this
`public void button1click(View v)
{
Button button2=(Button)getActionBar().getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.button2);
button2.setClickable(false);
button2.setEnabled(false);
}`

Answer (score 0):

You have to inflate the layout/views before using `findViewById`.

Like that:

```
private Toolbar toolbar;

// Set a Toolbar to replace the ActionBar.
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

cartLayout = (RelativeLayout) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.rl_cart);
```

**Your toolbar layout would be like this:**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_cart"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:padding="5dp">


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_cart" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**You can find more answer here:**

[How can I implement custom Action Bar with custom buttons in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15518414/how-can-i-implement-custom-action-bar-with-custom-buttons-in-android)

[How to set two custom actionbar button in left and right in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14210454/how-to-set-two-custom-actionbar-button-in-left-and-right-in-android)

Comment: thanks a lot, it worked. but i wonder if there is easier way to do it.