# Move actionbar logo to the left

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

I just want to move the logo in the actionbar from the center to the left, i tried like this but did not work

```
<item name="logo">imgname</item>
<item name="android:gravity">left</item>
```

this is my actual code

```
<style name="MyActionBar"
parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
<item name="android:background">@drawable/emgtxtbg</item>
<item name="logo">@drawable/emgtxt</item>
<item name="displayOptions">useLogo|showHome</item>
<!-- Support library compatibility -->
<item name="background">@drawable/emgtxtbg</item>
```

Comment: Try refer the below link,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14210454/how-to-set-two-custom-actionbar-button-in-left-and-right-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/imageView4"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:src="@drawable/adnace_search_i" />
```

Stay in touch with me if you find any problems.

Comment: my fault, im trying to do this in my customtheme.xml, your answer is right but not for my case