# Xamarin forms position of toolbar items for android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want the ToolbarItem Menu1 on the left side, but at this moment both are on right side.
How can I fix that?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="Dharma.LoginPage">
   <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
     <ToolbarItem Name="Menu1" Order="Primary" Priority="0" />
     <ToolbarItem Name="Menu2" Order="Primary" Priority="1" />
   </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
   <ContentPage.Content>
     <StackLayout Padding="30">
       <Label Text="Login Page" FontSize="20" />
     </StackLayout>
   </ContentPage.Content>
 </ContentPage>
```

Comment: There is no way to do this directly in `Xamarin.Forms` you will need to do a CustomRender for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned, this can only be done using a [custom renderer for your Page](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/contentpage/). Then you need to move all the menu item creation logic there since Xamarin's built in `ToolbarItem` will cause all sorts of issues with your custom logic. You can refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14210454/how-to-set-two-custom-actionbar-button-in-left-and-right-in-android) for more details on how to move your items to the left - it's kind of involved, so perhaps it's a better idea to just live with having them on the right.

Answer (score 9):

This is not Feasible solution. I know but for now I have tried this.
just add blank toolbaritems between `menu1` and `menu2` to create space between them.

So it will set at left and right accordingly

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
 <ToolbarItem Name="Menu1" Order="Primary" Priority="0" />
 <ToolbarItem Name="" Order="Primary" Priority="0" />
 <ToolbarItem Name="" Order="Primary" Priority="0" />
 <ToolbarItem Name="" Order="Primary" Priority="0" />
 <ToolbarItem Name="" Order="Primary" Priority="0" />
 <ToolbarItem Name="Menu2" Order="Primary" Priority="1" />
```

Answer (score 3):

This isn't currently supported in Forms.  To get around it, you could write a [Custom Renderer](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/) that overrides the base Android toolbar renderer.

Comment: If I am writing custom renderer, which would be static for all pages. If I need to change toolbar icon position after login would it be supported by custom rendere