# Center align toolbar items in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a content page with toolbar added as follows

**ContentPage**

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class ChartList : ContentPage
{
    public ChartList ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();

        //public class ToolbarItem : MenuItem
        ToolbarItem settings = new ToolbarItem
        {
            Icon = "icon.png",
            Text = "Settings",
            Command = new Command(this.ShowHomePage),
        };

        this.ToolbarItems.Add(settings);
    }

    private void ShowHomePage()
    {
        this.Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage());
    }
}
```

**App.Xaml.cs**

```
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ContentPage p = new MyHomeScreen2.MainPage();
        MainPage = new NavigationPage(p)
        {
            BarBackgroundColor = Color.Purple,
            BarTextColor = Color.White
        };
    }
```

I need to align the icon on the center of the toolbar. How to do it in Xamarin Forms?

[image]

Comment: I think you will need a custom renderer for this, check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36717697/xamarin-forms-position-of-toolbar-items-for-android?rq=1

Comment: @LIjo have you solved this issue?

Comment: @PaulKaram it is not required anymore if using Shell.

Comment: @Cfun I haven't been into Xamarin for a long time now, so you are most likely right. I am gonna hope back in soon, so that's nice information to have. Thank you.

Comment: @PaulKaram nice to have you back and have a bigger community using this amazing technology. Good to know it was helpful info.

Answer (score 1):

I know at the time of the question [Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/configuration#display-views-in-the-navigation-bar) was probably not introduced yet, but now if your app is based on Shell you can achieve it easily **without** even a custom renderer, and also customize your toolbar using [Shell.TitleView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/configuration#display-views-in-the-navigation-bar) as Microsoft example:

```
<ContentPage ...>
    <Shell.TitleView>
        <Image Source="xamarin_logo.png"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    </Shell.TitleView>
    ...
</ContentPage>
```

It will probably not be perfectly centered because of a bug in Xamarin.forms [Title View's content horizontal aligment](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/4848)