# How to add company logo to NavigationPage TitleIcon?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

So I'm trying to add a company logo to the middle of my `NavigationPage` Title section, and I have tried to use `NavigationPage.TitleIcon="companytitleicon.png"` inside `XAML`, but it doesn't display. I'm not certain if it's because the image has to be a certain size, and I cannot find information in the documentation.

I played around with other code as well, like calling `NavigationPage.SetTitleIcon` which takes a reference to a page and a FileImageSource like so:

`NavigationPage.SetTitleIcon(this, "/Assets/dischemtitleicon.png");`

I may be using it incorrectly, so I need a bit of advice, in general, with getting the logo to display on the Title section. I'll add a screenshot as well to specify the location and size of the logo. The logo is at least twice as wide as the height, eg. `120 x 50` ...

[image]

Any assistance will be truly appreciated. I'm also trying to get the colour of the `MasterDetail` bar to change, but that's not as crucial of an issue. (I added a global StaticResource that applies a fixed colour to all NavigationPage BarBackgroundColors)

Comment: I know it is an old question but please check if my post answers your question. Thanks.

Comment: @Cfun I still have the project files handy, so I will take a look and let you know asap, thank you so much for the response, I had recently wondered if I would ever get one.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Xamarin.Forms app based on [Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/) then you can easily achieve this using [Shell.TitleView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/configuration#display-views-in-the-navigation-bar) without the need of a custom renderer, define your title content, bind it or even style it as you like.

You could refer to my similar answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65062752/522820