# Xamarin Forms: How to align the contentPage toolbar image to center?

Tags: xamarin.forms, toolbar, center

I have added an icon to the toolbar by the following code, but how can I align it to center. Now it is on the right end. In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36717697/xamarin-forms-position-of-toolbar-items-for-android?rq=1) thread telling it is not possible in xamarin forms.

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Icon="logo-final.jpg"/>
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

I need the icon on the center like below screen.

[image]

Please suggest a solution for this feature?

Comment: Hi, Have you solved this?

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Ya solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try Navigation Title view

```
<ContentPage>
    <NavigationPage.TitleView>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center" Spacing="10">
            <Image Source="iconXamagon.png">               
            </Image>           
        </StackLayout>
    </NavigationPage.TitleView>
    ...
</ContentPage>
```

For more referance  https://montemagno.com/xamarin-forms-icons-in-navigation-toolbar/