# how to align toolbaritems in xamarin forms for cross platform

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, cross-platform, toolbaritems

so for example

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Name="logo" Icon="businessName.png" Priority="0" Order="Primary"/>
    <ToolbarItem Name="shoppingCartImage" Icon="shopping_cart_IMG.png" Priority="0" Order="Primary"/> Activated="Onclick" />
    <ToolbarItem x:Name="NumberOfItemsInCart" Priority="0" Order="Primary"/>
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

will display all items to the right of the toolbar...I would like the logo in the centre and then shopping cart image and label for number in shopping cart to the right...

Read many examples online regarding creating a customer render...([Xamarin forms position of toolbar items for android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36717697/xamarin-forms-position-of-toolbar-items-for-android?rq=1))

is this still the case? as these Q's were asked years ago...has xamarin been updated to include alignment of items in the toolbar or do I need to create a custom render... please advise thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue(cannot set the icon to center in xamarin forms code) just happened in Android, you do not need to create a custom renderer in Android.

First of all, please open the `Toolbar.xml` file in *Resources/layout* folder,this is what you set in the `MainActivity`, which Xamarin.Forms will use to inflate it. Add a `ImageView` to the `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` like following code.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" >

<ImageView
        android:contentDescription="businessname icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/businessname"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Here is running screenshot.

[image]

Here is a helpful link, you can refer to it.

https://montemagno.com/xamarin-forms-icons-in-navigation-toolbar/

Comment: ahh thats brilliant thanks for the help...only thing is tho my audience is going to be ios and andriod...so maybe in the long run it would be more feasible to create the custom render...more work now but as I say I need it for ios also

Comment: You can see link in the answer, it have solution about iOS

Comment: If the answer is helpful, please accept it as answer, it will help others who have similar issues

Comment: If you used custom renderer,you need to get the action bar then create a imageview, set the imageView to the action bar and set the layout in the center. I have tried that way, but the action bar always get null, we need set a new action in the main activity, that’s too complex.

Comment: thats brilliant thanks for your help. got both in the link