# Xamarin Android: How to align items to the left of an Actionbar

Tags: c#, android-actionbar, xamarin.android

I have a custom Actionbar and currently im trying to align the menu-icon to be on the left of the title.
[My actionbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xXGC.png)

How can i achieve that?

Heres my "menu.xml":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item 
  android:id="@+id/menu_OpenMenu"
  android:title="OpenMenu"
  android:icon="@drawable/Image_OpenMenu"
  app:showAsAction="always" />
<item 
  android:id="@+id/action_Search"
  android:title="Search"
  android:icon="@drawable/Image_Search"
  android:queryHint="Search..."
  app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
  app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>  
</menu>
```

And heres how i inflate it:

```
public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
    {
        MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.Top_Menus_Main, menu);

        // SearchView
        var item = menu.FindItem(Resource.Id.action_Search);
        var searchActionView = MenuItemCompat.GetActionView(item);
        searchView = searchActionView as Android.Support.V7.Widget.SearchView;

        return base.OnCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Action bar button are aligned at the right side you can not align them at the left side without custom view.

check out this [How to set two custom actionbar button in left and right in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14210454/how-to-set-two-custom-actionbar-button-in-left-and-right-in-android)